# Schoology API: "users/me" duplicate nonce error

Tags: javascript, api, schoology

I struggled with this annoying bug for a very long time. The issue was when trying to get the users UID via the two-legged API `users/me` it would result in an response from the API: `Duplicate timestamp/nonce combination, possible replay attack.  Request rejected.` My work around for a while was basically brute forcing this API endpoint until it responded. This worked sometimes but is obviously not practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through post after post of people also having this problem I looked at the answers from Schoology support and they all said visit the docs, which I have looked over  multiple times before. however this time I scrolled down and found a "short-cut" as they called it to get the UID:

[image: Schoology API Docs]

So instead of trying to use the `users/me` endpoint you simply use the endpoint: `/app-user-info` which returns a JSON with timestamp and UID!

After you get the UID you can freely access the `users/me` endpoint by replacing me with the UID like so: `users/{UID}`

URL:
`https://api.schoology.com/v1/app-user-info`

two-legged Authorization header:

```
OAuth realm="Schoology API",
oauth_consumer_key="{CONSUMER_KEY}",
oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",
oauth_timestamp="{TIMESTAMP}",
oauth_token="",
oauth_nonce="{RANDOM_CHARS}",
oauth_version="1.0",
oauth_signature="{CONSUMER_SECRET}%26"
```